# Prove that $\sec^2(x) - \tan^2(x) = 1$ given that $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I need to prove from $\sin^2(x) +\cos^2(x) = 1$ that $\sec^2(x) - \tan^2(x) = 1$.

Comment: Hint: rewrite the second thing in terms of sines and cosines ($\tan=\sin\!/\!\cos,\sec=1/\!\cos$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide through by $\cos^2(x)$ and then subtract $\tan^2(x)$ from both sides of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \sec^2(x)-\tan^2(x)=1 $$
$$ \frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}-\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}=1 $$
$$ \frac{1-\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}=1 $$
$$ 1-\sin^2(x)= \cos^2(x) $$
$$ 1= \sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x) $$